# why is WMVIDEOINFOHEADER.rcSource causing a invalid pointer

Tags: c++, winapi

I don't understand how this:`((WMVIDEOINFOHEADER*)&VideoMediaType->pbFormat)->rcSource = rc;` is causing (WM_MEDIA_TYPE*)VideoMediaType to become invaid. When the rest of the code block doesn't seem to have a problem.

```
WM_MEDIA_TYPE* VideoMediaType = NULL;
VideoMediaType = (WM_MEDIA_TYPE*) new BYTE[MediaType];

Status = VideoMediaProps->GetMediaType(VideoMediaType, &MediaType);
RECT rc;
rc.left   = 0;
rc.top    = 0;
rc.right  = 640;
rc.bottom = 480;

((WMVIDEOINFOHEADER*)&VideoMediaType->pbFormat)->rcSource = rc; //<--Causing the issue.
((WMVIDEOINFOHEADER*)&VideoMediaType->pbFormat)->rcTarget = rc;
((WMVIDEOINFOHEADER*)&VideoMediaType->pbFormat)->dwBitRate = BitRate;
((WMVIDEOINFOHEADER*)&VideoMediaType->pbFormat)->AvgTimePerFrame = ( (LONGLONG) 10000000 ) / ( (LONGLONG) 30 );
((WMVIDEOINFOHEADER*)&VideoMediaType->pbFormat)->bmiHeader.biHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
((WMVIDEOINFOHEADER*)&VideoMediaType->pbFormat)->bmiHeader.biWidth  = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
```

No matter where I put that line, once the debugger gets to that line in debug mode 'VideoMediaType' becomes invalid. If I comment that line out the pointer stays valid and the program executes as expected.

Comment: What is the `Status` value exactly, and clarify what do you mean by "becomes invalid".

Comment: Your code is corrupting the heap.  You **must** call GetMediaType() twice.  First with the 1st argument set to NULL, that returns the size of the structure you need.  Then you know how much to allocate.

Comment: @RomanR. Status is just a 'HRESULT' variable and by invalid I mean a bad pointer as visual studio likes to call it.

Comment: @HansPassant I did call GetMediaType() twice and I get a valid pointer, I just decided not to show that much code in the above post.

Comment: You are interested in `Status` value, it's clear that the type is `HRESULT`. The point is that if it indicates an error, then the entire `VideoMediaType->pbFormat` thing is undefined and it would explain the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: `pbFormat` is a pointer, but you're dereferencing the *address* of that pointer instead of the pointer itself.